# How to print only short name in glossary of acronym package

Tags: acronyms

I want to achieve the following. I have an acronym in English like LED and want to display in the text the German name

*Blabbla bla Licht emittierende Diode (**LED**) bla bla blabla.*,

and in the glossary the English

***LED** engl. Light-emitting diode*.

There is the possibility to define a long and short form acronym with the `acronym` package:

```
\acro{<acronym>}[<short name>]{<full name>}
```

Can I use this to print only the short name (engl. Light-emitting diode) in the glossary and using `\acf{<acronym>}` in the text to print the full name?

Comment: No, the short name is _LED_. The [`acro`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/acro) package allows you to add extra information to the list of acronyms.

Comment: So is it preferable to use the `acro` package instead of the `acronym` package?

Comment: I wouldn't say that in general. Depends on what you need. You should have a look at the documentation and then decide for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be the package `glossaries`.

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{led}{type=\acronymtype, 
name={LED}, 
description={Light-emitting diode}, 
first={Licht emittierende Diode (LED)}}
\begin{document}
Blabbla bla  \gls{led}  bla bla blabla. \\
Again blabbla bla  \gls{led}  bla bla blabla.
\printglossary[type=acronym]
\end{document}
```

Note that you will need compile this with

```
pdflatex file.tex
makeglossaries file
pdflatex file.tex
```